# Using Active Directory and Open ID to authenticate a Play Framework based application

Tags: openid, playframework

I have an application I am building using the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org). I would like this application to authenticate users using Open ID and Active Directory. Is this possible? Please excuse my ignorance as I am not a J2EE expert but come from a deep knowledge of the .Net framework and some experience writing Java applications. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There's an existing play.lib for [openid integration in your application](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/openid) and a [Play! module for OAuth](http://www.playframework.org/modules/oauth-1.0/home).

I'm not aware of an Active Directory related module or lib in Play!. The Play! community is friendly so try asking your question on the [dedicated Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework).

You'll probably have some additional work (and security concerns) if you want to integrate multiple identification schemes.

Edit: there's [a thread about LDAP integration in Play!](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/fb167d122d37ec32)

Answer (score 1):

There is an article (in French) [here](http://www.coding-stories.com/2010/11/03/authentification-ldap-avec-play-framework/) that shows how to authenticate using Spring LDAP and the Play! framework.